# How to open highlighted URLs in a new Tab using IE7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-7

I would like to drag text URLs to open them in a new tab.

This is a feature that actually made me work with IE7. I can't find this in IE8, not even through add-ons. IE7 had this add-on though, I think it's called "drag.. something".

Comment: My God The Capitalization Is Killing Me!

Comment: You show no respect for the people who you are asking help from. Why should we care? Edit your post, write proper sentences (not knowing English isn't an excuse to write as you write) and don't ask something in your title and something else completely different in your post. Voting to close

Comment: @ADwarf It's actually a (lame but) valid question. Dimona, please at least *try* to write proper English.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Utilu IE Collection](http://utilu.com/IECollection/)?
It's contains a lot of different versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

There's the *[quero Toolbar](http://www.quero.at/)* which offers the following feature:

> *Go to text URLs*
>   Jump to URLs that are not hyperlinked.

So if that's what you need, you can use it in IE9 and any other IE version you want.

---

There's also [*SuperAddOn*](http://superaddon.com/), which offers a [drag/drop](http://superaddon.com/#Super_Drag_Drop) functionality:

> *Up (U) direction command:*
>   Search the text (using an IE bar, e.g. the Search bar) or **Open URL in a New IE Tab**.

Answer (score 0):

I can drag-and-drop it to the address bar, the title bar, and the content window in IE8.  Where are you having trouble dragging and dropping to?